# State machine problem

Tags: c++, interrupt

I am trying to record the pulses from a water flow sensor using a state machine. My goal is to count the pulses until the flow stops (i.e. the rotor inside comes to rest). This will constitute a single reading. if there is no new pulse/interrupt 5 seconds after the rotor is stopped, the total pulse count is printed and pulse count is reset to zero for the subsequent readings.

However, in practice, I get a pulse count even when the sensor rotor is moving. The pulse count gets resets after 5 sec but the pulses between the new reading and until the rotor is stopped are somehow missed.

Could you please help me figure what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TelnetStream.h>

const byte pulsePin = 22;
byte volatile triggerCounter = 0;

byte newState = 0;

unsigned long newTime = 0;
unsigned long oldTime = 0;

unsigned long pulseCountNew = 0;

portMUX_TYPE mux = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;

void IRAM_ATTR handleInterrupt()
{
  portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&mux);
  triggerCounter++;
  portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&mux);
}

void stateMachine()
{

  switch (newState)
  {

  case 0 /* Reset */:
    newState = 1;

    break;

  case 1 /* Start */:

    if (triggerCounter > 0)
    {
      newState = 2;
    }
    break;

  case 2 /* Pulse count start */:

    pulseCountNew++;
    triggerCounter--;
    newTime = millis();
    newState = 3;

    break;

  case 3 /* Pulse count stop */:

    if (triggerCounter > 0)
    {
      newState = 2;
    }

    if (newTime - oldTime >= 5000)
    {
      oldTime = newTime;
      newState = 4;
    }
    break;

  case 4 /* Cycle complete */:
    newState = 0;
    TelnetStream.println("State 4");

    break;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(pulsePin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pulsePin), handleInterrupt, FALLING);
  TelnetStream.begin();
}

void loop()
{

  if (newState == 4)
  {

    TelnetStream.println(pulseCountNew);
    pulseCountNew = 0;
  }

  stateMachine();
}
```

Comment: `The pulse count gets resets after 5 sec` ... don't reset the counter ... refer to how millis() is used

Comment: do you have less than 255 readings in one batch? you use `byte`

Comment: The code will have a mich better readability if you use makros or an enum for the state, so you can have something like `case RESET:`...

Comment: You should have all code that is relevant for the state machine in the switch block. The `TelnetStream.println()` might be ok in thw `loop()`, but `pulseCountNew=0` should be in `case 4`.

Comment: `triggerCounter` is declared as `byte`, so it can't become negative. The statements `triggerCounter--` and `if(triggerCounter>0)` are error prone and probably don't what you expect.

Comment: @SimSon I didn't know about enum but you are right. Need to learn it's  usage

Comment: @Juraj I suppose you are talking about trigger counter being declared as type byte. Since in the state 2, the trigger will be decremented so I thought the count wouldn't go as high as 255. But thinking about it now I assume that may happen

Comment: yes it is possible to always take the value, add it to total and reset. I don't know how fast the value increments in your project. using byte is good because the operations are atomic and don't require to block interrupts. but using larger type allows spending more time in loop without checking the counter and that helps if you do networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this usually without an extra state variable.

```
unsigned long readSensor() {
  const unsigned long READING_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5000;
  static unsigned long lastReadingMillis;
  static unsigned long lastCounterValue;

  noInterrupts();
  unsigned long counter = triggerCounter;
  interrupts();

  if (counter != lastCounterValue) { // if new reading
    lastReadingMillis = millis(); // reset timout timer
    lastCounterValue = counter; 
  } else if (counter > 0 && (millis() - lastReadingMillis) > READING_TIMEOUT_MILLIS) { // if something was counted and is timeout
    noInterrupts();
    triggerCounter = 0;
    interrupts();
    lastCounterValue = 0;
    lastReadingMillis = 0;
    return counter;
  }
  return 0;
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long value = readSensor();
  if (value) {
    Serial.println(value);
  }
}
```

sorry, the code is not tested.

Comment: I thought using a simple state machine would be simpler than using  multiple conditional statements. However, your example is much more compact.